# ES6 Array destructuring weirdness

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Can anyone explain, why the following happens with ES6 array destructuring?

```
let a, b, c
[a, b] = ['A', 'B']
[b, c] = ['BB', 'C']
console.log(`a=${a} b=${b} c=${c}`)

// expected: a=A b=BB c=C
// actual:   a=BB b=C c=undefined
```

http://codepen.io/ronkot/pen/WxRqXg?editors=0011

Comment: put `;` after each line

Comment: yup, tested that, @PranavCBalan's comment works

Comment: This is why ASI is a misfeature.

Comment: True, @PranavCBalan's solution works. Wow, for me this is first case where the semicolons really matter in js code. I prefer semicolon-less code for cleaner syntax, but maybe I have to start to use them. Can anyone explain, why in this case the semicolons are really needed?

Comment: @ronkot Almost any time you start a line with array indexer or parenthesis you're going to have an issue ([Example](https://jsfiddle.net/h32muwxk/)). Most devs who prefer semi-colonless start the line with a `;` to fix ASI related issues.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As others have said, you're missing semicolons. But…

> Can anyone explain?

There are no [semicolons automatically inserted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1048572) between your lines to separate the "two" statements, because it is valid as a single statement. It is parsed (and evaluated) as

```
let a = undefined, b = undefined, c = undefined;
[a, b] = (['A', 'B']
[(b, c)] = ['BB', 'C']);
console.log(`a=${a} b=${b} c=${c}`);
```

wherein

- `[a, b] = …;` is a destructuring assignment as expected
- `(… = ['BB', 'C'])` is an assignment expression assigning the array to the left hand side, and evaluating to the array
- `['A', 'B'][…]` is a [property reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) on an array literal
- `(b, c)` is using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), evaluating to `c` (which is `undefined`)

If you want to omit semicolons and let them be automatically inserted where ever <s>possible</s> needed, you will [need to put one at the *start*](https://web.archive.org/web/20201206065632/http://inimino.org/%7Einimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) of every line that begins with `(`, `[`, `/`, `+`, `-` or `` ` ``.

Comment: Why did it turn `[b, c]` to a `[(b, c)]` actually?

Comment: Wow, this is the real answer for the question.... I were thinking what happening there... Now it's clear....

Comment: @zerkms: Because I like introducing grouping operators… in this case to emphasise that it is not an array literal with two elements

Comment: is `['A', 'B'][b, c]` will get property `b` and `c` of array elements ?

Comment: After testing with several cases, Ithink `['A', 'B'][b, c]` ==> `['A', 'B'][c]`

Comment: @PranavCBalan: no, `b, c` evaluates to the value of `c`, so it will assign to the property with the name `"undefined"` on the array

Comment: Marked as correct answer due to nice explanation. Another correct answer mark would go to @oleg's great answer.

Comment: For those interested, here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion

Answer (score 6):

You've fallen into a trap of line wrapping and automatic semicolon insertion rules in JavaScript.

Take this example:

```
let x = [1, 2]
[2, 1]
```

It's the interpreted as:

```
let x = [1, 2][2, 1] // === [1, 2][(2, 1)] === [1, 2][1] === 2
```

That weird `[(2, 1)]` thing above is related to how [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) works.

Thus, your example:

```
let a, b, c
[a, b] = ['A', 'B']
[b, c] = ['BB', 'C']
console.log(`a=${a} b=${b} c=${c}`)
```

Is interpreted as:

```
let a, b, c
[a, b] = ['A', 'B'][b, c] = ['BB', 'C']
console.log(`a=${a} b=${b} c=${c}`)
```

Now, if you insert a semicolon, it will work as you intended:

```
let a, b, c
[a, b] = ['A', 'B']; // note a semicolon here
[b, c] = ['BB', 'C']
console.log(`a=${a} b=${b} c=${c}`)
```

Also, it's a good idea to check your code by pasting it into [Babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2015-loose%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20a%2C%20b%2C%20c%0A%5Ba%2C%20b%5D%20%3D%20%5B'A'%2C%20'B'%5D%0A%5Bb%2C%20c%5D%20%3D%20%5B'BB'%2C%20'C'%5D%0Aconsole.log(%60a%3D%24%7Ba%7D%20b%3D%24%7Bb%7D%20c%3D%24%7Bc%7D%60)) to see the generated output:

```
'use strict';

var a = void 0,
    b = void 0,
    c = void 0;

var _ref = ['A', 'B'][(b, c)] = ['BB', 'C'];

a = _ref[0];
b = _ref[1];

console.log('a=' + a + ' b=' + b + ' c=' + c);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have forgotten the line breaks ';'. Below is the corrected code. Please try:

```
let a,b,c
[a, b] = ['A', 'B'];
[b, c] = ['BB', 'C'];
console.log(`a=${a} b=${b} c=${c}`)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained why `;` is necessary there.

Comment: I believe the following expression will shed more light: `let [a, b] = ['A', 'B'],[b, c] = ['BB', 'C'];`

Comment: It would, if you additionally explain why it is syntactically correct and its semantics.

Answer (score -1):

```
let a, b, c
[a, b] = ['A', 'B']***;***
[b, c] = ['BB', 'C']
console.log(`a=${a} b=${b} c=${c}`)
```

> console: a=A b=BB c=C