# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment in Chromium Browser

Tags: javascript, reference, chromium

I have a function like this

```
function makeIJKFromId(id) {
    return id.split("_").splice(1);
}
```

and this statement in timetable.js gives error(Only in Chromium Browser)

```
[i, j, k] = makeIJKFromId(e.target.id);
```

Error : Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Screenshot attached :[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuFcL.png)

then when i have made change like this

```
[i, j, k](makeIJKFromId(e.target.id));
```

it worked.

But I don't know why it worked? Isn't function destructuring allowed in Chromium?

Comment: Perhaps, you need a semicolon at the end of the line before `[i, j, k] = makeIJKFromId(e.target.id);`. See [ES6 Array destructuring weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38050480/704244)