# Interesting behavior about ES6 array destructuring and swapping

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I just noticed that the following code, without immediately referencing `one` after `let [one, two] = [1, 2]`, trying `[one, two] = [two, one]` would crash:

```js
let [one, two, three] = [1, 2, 3]
[one, two] = [two, one] // CRASH! one is not defined
console.log(one, two)
```

However, simply adding a not-used `one` between the declaration and swapping suddenly allows the code, but incorrectly:

```js
let [one, two, three] = [1, 2, 3]
one // inserted here
[one, two] = [two, one] // no longer crashes! but not actually swapping
console.log(one, two) // should be '2 1', but shows '1 2' instead
```

Whereas the below code gives the expected swapping effect

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 3;

[a, b] = [b, a];
console.log(a); // 3
console.log(b); // 1
```

Can someone explain why such behavior exists? Thanks!

Comment: add semicolon at the end of every line. there is no issue in your code

Comment: possible duplicate of [ES6 array desctructuring weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38050219/1048572)

Comment: This is why semicolons exist, leaving them out is asking for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a semicolon to the 1st line, because the interpreter assumes that lines 1 and 2 declarations happen together, and `one` (and `two`) is not defined yet:

```js
let [one, two, three] = [1, 2, 3];
[one, two] = [two, one]
console.log(one, two)
```

Comment: Ooops, seem to be the case. Very interesting to see that losing semicolon is actually causing troubles. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Cause its parsed like this:

```
 let [one, two, three] = [1, 2, 3][one, two] = [one, two]
```

To make it work, always suround destructuring assignments with parens:

```
 let [one, two, three] = [1, 2, 3];
 ([one, two] = [two, one]);
 console.log(one, two);
```

And never ever trust ASI, there are some cases like this were it goes wrong.

Comment: Surrounding the assignment with parentheses doesn't help if the previous line doesn't have a semicolon.

Comment: @bergi yes but its generally a good habit, especially when doing object destructuring

Comment: Yes, for objects it's necessary when not in a variable declaration, but not for arrays. Here they seem superfluous to me.