# Ambiguous array assignments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

After watching this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49292669/interesting-behavior-about-es6-array-destructuring-and-swapping), I came to know

```js
let a = [1, 2] [3, 4] = [5, 6];

console.log(a);
```

is valid JavaScript code but, I'm not able to understand, how it is working.
Can anyone explain working flow of above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After executing a lot of variations of

`let a = [1, 2] [3, 4] = [5, 6];`

I came to know

`[1, 2] [3, 4]` is equivalent to `[1, 2][4]` where `[1, 2]` represents an `array` while `[4]` represents 5th index of `[1, 2]` array but could not find any official documentation.

**Update**
I was wrong about documentation as mentioned in comments, `[]` in `[3, 4]` is Property accessor while `3, 4` are two different code statements separated by [Comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). In comma operator, every statement separated by `,` is executed from left to right and result of last statement is returned.

Above code now simplifies to

`let a = [1, 2][4] = [5, 6];`

which is comparatively easy to understand. If we simplify it little bit more it becomes

```js
let arr = [1, 2];
let a = arr[4] = [5, 6];

console.log(a);
console.log(arr);
```

Now it is very easy to explain it `arr[4] = [5, 6]` assigns `[5, 6]` to 5th index of `arr` and `a = arr[4]` assigns 5th index of `arr` to `a` which is now `[5, 6]` so `[5, 6]` is assigned to `a`.

Now current value of `a` is `[5, 6]` and current value of `arr` is `[ 1, 2, undefined, undefined, [ 5, 6 ] ]`

Lets rewrite above code again

```js
let arr = [1, 2];
let a = arr[3, 4] = [5, 6];

console.log(a);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `3, 4` is an expression that uses the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). Both sub-expressions joined by a comma operator are evaluated and the value of the expression is the value of the last sub-expression. In this example, the value of expression `3, 4` is `4`.

Comment: _“could not find any official documentation”_ — how about [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)?

Comment: Thanks @axiac and Xufox for pointing about comma operator, let me update my answer